# Haskell Twitch Library not working as expected

Tags: haskell, file-watcher, program-flow

I am playing around with the [Twitch](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/twitch-0.1.7.1/docs/Twitch.html) library:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell   #-}
module Main where

import Twitch
import Data.Default
import Turtle.Prelude
import RIO

main :: IO ()
main = do
        print "hi"
        let p = "C:\\Users\\unicorn\\programming\\listenerDir" 
        print "before" 
        liftIO $ runWithConfig p ((\c -> c {dirs=[p]}) def) $ do -- marked
          "*.csv" |> \f -> print f                               -- marked
        print "here"
        return ()
```

when i compile and run the above program without the `liftIO ...` (so leaving out the marked lines) call it runs fine and prints the messages. (but then obviously, the file listener is not registered and running, so it is not the desired outcome.)

However, when compiled and run as is, it doesn't do anything, not even printing `hi` and `before`. any idea why that is the case here?

I have tried to follow the examples of the library but I can't figure out why it just hangs.

---

**UPDATE:**

apparently it has something to do with the dirs replacement I am doing for the def configuration

**UPDATE:**

I have also tried it the following way:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell   #-}
module Main where

import Twitch
import Data.Default
import Turtle.Prelude
import RIO
import System.IO.Unsafe
import System.FilePath.Windows

main :: IO ()
main = do
        let p   = "C:\\" </> "Users" </> "unicorn" </> "programming" </> "simpleUID" </> "lib_app_setup" </> "kofax-valet" </> "testingDir" 
            ops = Options LogToStdout Nothing (Just p) False DebounceDefault 0 300 False
        print "starting"
        print p 
        defaultMainWithOptions ops $ do
          "*.csv" > \f -> print f
```

with the same result

[looking it up in the source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/twitch-0.1.7.1/docs/src/Twitch-Main.html#defaultMainWithOptions), `defaultMainWithOptions` should also print stuff to stdout; but that doesn't happen either...

*fyi: I asked this question [on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/hvnuw5/anybody_proficient_with_the_twitch_filedirectory/) but didn't get an answer there, so I suspected a bigger problem that might not be just my unfamiliarity with the library and therefore posted it here*

**Update:**
this is the full output of `cabal run` for the second code:

```sh
unicorn@LAPTOP ~/programming/haskell/listenerTest
$ cabal run
Build profile: -w ghc-8.10.1 -O1
In order, the following will be built (use -v for more details):
 - listenerTest-0.1.0.0 (exe:listenerTest) (file Main.hs changed)
Preprocessing executable 'listenerTest' for listenerTest-0.1.0.0..
Building executable 'listenerTest' for listenerTest-0.1.0.0..
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             
( Main.hs, C:\Users\unicorn\programming\haskell\listenerTest\dist-newstyle
\build\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.10.1\listenerTest-0.1.0.0\x\listenerTest\build
\listenerTest\listenerTest-tmp\Main.o )
Linking C:\Users\unicorn\programming\haskell\listenerTest\dist-newstyle\build
\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.10.1\listenerTest-0.1.0.0\x\listenerTest\build
\listenerTest\listenerTest.exe ...





unicorn@LAPTOP ~/programming/haskell/listenerTest
$
```

afterwards i had to Ctrl+c and then also kill the task

Comment: I'm missing something here. If runnig without `liftIO` works fine... what's the problem then?

Comment: sorry I may have written it wrong;
i updated the question with a better description of that part. running without the liftIO means that the file-listener is not registered and therefore not running; it is just the print statements then

Comment: wierd... I cannot spot the problem. I am a linux user and I wonder if the windows-like path (with \\\) has something to do with issue. Can you try to import `System.FilePath.Windows` and write `p = "C:\\" </> "Users" </> "unicorn" ...`? problably is not the problem but just in case (If you know for sure that the path is ok just don't do it)

Comment: I suspected this too; I tried to do it another way first; and now with the `filesystem` library approach you recommended; unfortunately i get the same result; - the program starts running but doesn't do anything, when i quit it, I also have to kill the task as it is running on; so it seems something has started but I am unable figure it out